# JavaScript Getting ID of A Div

Tags: javascript

I have a `div` box with its `id` and an `textarea`.
When I click on my `div` box I should get `div` ID through Javascript and get it printed on the `textarea`. I have tried but its not working. when I click the text area it says "undefined". Kindly help me.

Here is the code:

```
<html>
<head>

<script type="text/javascript">
function get_id()
{
    var divEls = document.getElementsByTagName("div");
    var textEl = document.getElementById("mytextarea");
    textEl.value=divEls.id;
}
</script>

</head>
<body>
    <div id="mydiv" onclick="get_id()" style='border-width:1px;border-color:#C0C0C0;border-style: solid;background-color:#C0C0C0;width:130px;height:10px;'>
    </div>

    <textarea id="mytextarea"> </textarea>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: `divEls` is a nodeList, which is essentially an array of nodes, you'd need to use `divEls[0].id`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok I figured it out. `document.getElementsByTagName("div")` will return all the elements which have tag name div as an array of nodes. Here in your code there is only one div element hence first element is div itself. As in an array first element has number index = 0 so we can get first by  `document.getElementsByTagName("div")[0]` or in your code `divEls[0]`, and then we can get its id by simply getting  `divEls[0].id`. Now as we have got the div id we can set the value of text area equal to this div id as: `textEl.value = divEls[0].id` Here is your code with changes. Hope this Helps

```
<html>
<head>

<script type="text/javascript">
function get_id()
{
var divEls = document.getElementsByTagName("div");
var textEl = document.getElementById("mytextarea");
/*get the first item in the nodelist ie divEls[0] = document.getElementsByTagName("div")[0] and then get its id by
its id by divEls[0] */
textEl.value = divEls[0].id; 

}
</script>

</head>
<body>
<div id="mydiv" onclick="get_id()" style='border-width:1px;border-color:#C0C0C0;border-style: solid;background-color:#C0C0C0;width:130px;height:10px;'>
</div>

<textarea id="mytextarea"> </textarea>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 2):

`getElementsByTagName` returns a `nodeList` of DOM nodes, which acts like an array.

You'll need to select the first item in the node list before you can access the node's ID:

```
textEl.value = divEls[0].id;
```

Alternatively, you could have passed `this` to `get_id()`:

```
function get_id(node) {
  var textEl = document.getElementById('mytextarea');
  textEl.value = node.id;
}

onclick="get_id(this)"
```

But honestly, all of the JavaScript should be external to your HTML file. HTML belongs in `.html` files, CSS belongs in `.css` files and JS belongs in `.js` files.

```
//i haven't checked this code, and you probably want to modify it to be more generic.
window.onload = function () {
  var myDiv, myTextArea;
  myDiv = document.getElementById('mydiv');
  myTextArea = document.getElementById('mytextarea');
  myDiv.onclick = function () {
    myTextArea.value = myDiv.id;
  };
};
```

Comment: thank you so much. you guys are really nice. nearly all the answers deserve vote up

Answer (score 1):

Rewrite your code as below:

```
<html>
<head>
     <script type="text/javascript">
          function get_id(element) {
               var textEl = document.getElementById("mytextarea");
               textEl.value = element.id;
          }
     </script>
</head>
<body>
     <div id="mydiv" onclick="get_id(this)" style='border-width: 1px; border-color: #C0C0C0;
          border-style: solid; background-color: #C0C0C0; width: 130px; height: 10px;'>
     </div>
     <textarea id="mytextarea"> </textarea>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1):

When you use `getElementsByTagName`, you get ALL of the elements with that tag as an array.
If you want the first `DIV` then you need to add `[0]` this way:

```
 var divEls = document.getElementsByTagName("div")[0];
```

The remaining code is ok.

Answer (score 1):

`getElementsByTagName` returns an `array` even if it contains only one object. You should access it like this:

```
function get_id()
{
    var divEls = document.getElementsByTagName("div");
    var textEl = document.getElementById("mytextarea");
    textEl.value=divEls[0].id;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

`divels` is, as the plural is indicating, an Array (correct: a [NodeList](https://developer.mozilla.org/En/DOM/NodeList)), which has no id property. Its items have, so eg. `textEl.value=divEls[0].id;` will work (if the List is empty, this will throw an error).

Answer (score 0):

try this function

```
function get_id()
{
var divEls = document.getElementsByTagName("div");
var textEl = document.getElementById("mytextarea");
textEl.value=divEls.item(0).id;
}
```